# Android: Swipe between 2 fragment in view pager, on page change listener doesn't work

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

in my Android app I have a view pager with a swipe between 2 fragments. It works perfectly. But if I add a onPageChangeListener event, when I swipe between 2 fragment nothing happens. No error message, the fragment swipe well, but I don't see any print message (only when the activity appears for the first time, I see "A" message). Why? How can I call an event, when I swipe between the 2 fragments? Thank much to all.

This is the class of view pager:

```html
package com.mycompany.myapp.Views;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.mycompany.myapp.R;
import com.mycompany.myapp.Utility.ClsPageAdapter;
import com.mycompany.myapp.Utility.ClsScreenAnalyzer;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

public class ControlActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private ClsPageAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    private static String urlString;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_control);
        this.initialisePaging();

        ViewPager controlSlide = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    

        controlSlide.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

            // optional
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                System.out.print("A");
            }

            // optional
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                System.out.print("B");
            }

            // optional
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                System.out.print("C");
            }
        });
    }

    private void initialisePaging() {

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ControlActivity1.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ControlActivity2.class.getName()));
        this.mPagerAdapter  = new ClsPageAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    }
}
```

And this is the ClsPageAdapter

```html
package com.mycompany.myapp.Utility;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * The <code>PagerAdapter</code> serves the fragments when paging.
 * 
 */
public class ClsPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;
    /**
     * @param fm
     * @param fragments
     */
    public ClsPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter#getItem(int)
     */
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getCount()
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }
}
```

Edit: I have also tried in this way (with only one view declaration) but nothing change. Other ideas? Thank!

```html
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_control);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        //Initialize paging
        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ControlActivity1.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ControlActivity2.class.getName()));
        this.mPagerAdapter  = new ClsPageAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
        
        pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            // optional
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                System.out.print("A");
            }

            // optional
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                System.out.print("B");
            }

            // optional
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                System.out.print("C");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is `controlSlide` in your MainActivity ?

Comment: Thank for your very fast answer! Control slide is the view pager. My activity has a top image view, a central view pager, and a bottom image view. All in a linear layout. Now I update my question. Thank! PS Sorry, I haven't copy the control slide row and one other row, due to a "//" tag. Now the code is the same of my app.

Comment: Where is `setAdapter()` for `controlSlide `

Comment: Thank Kathi! Is at the end of the first code block.

Comment: See my answer, your initiate Viewpager two times in your code. one with `pager` one with `controlSlide ` . and you `setAdapter()` for `pager` !!!

Comment: No, this is not the reason. Check my last answer: I have tried to merge initialize paging in on create, so with only one declaration for my view, but nothing change. Other ideas? Thank!